# Casting IObservable<byte> to byte in C#

Tags: c#, functional-programming, observable, reactive-programming

I have a method with the following type signature

```
public IObservable<string> Process(IObservable<Tuple<byte,byte>> source)
```

Within this method I would like to execute some code based off the value of the first byte of that tuple, something like this

```
if ((source.Select(value => value.Item1.Equals(connect_byte))) & (this.connected == false)){
            // Do some stuff
            return source.Select(value => "Success");
        }
```

I have the error

```
Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'IObservable<bool>' and 'bool'
```

My (general) question is how to I convert an `IObservable<type>` to `type`.  The framework I'm working with passes everything around as `IObservable<>`, but I find these very difficult to work with, due to the above errors.

Comment: Please edit the question so that it includes a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

`IObservable<T>` is a *stream* of `T`, not a `T`.  You can't cast it.  You can only work with the items in the stream as they come through.

- By using `Select` you can map values from one thing to another.
- By using `Where` you can filter out values you don't want

By composing the streams you can create more advanced behaviour.  It's worth reading up on the Rx operators to see what's possible, but remember you're always working with a 0-n item stream of values.

I don't know the intent of your original code, but this should give you a stream of `"Success"` values whenever you get a `connect_byte` and `connected` is `false`

```
source.Where(value => value.Item1 == connect_byte && !this.connected)
      .Select(_ => "Success")
```